# Converting Excel spreadsheets to Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, file-conversion

Any idea how to convert Excel spreadsheets to Word or if it's an impossible task? I often deal with large datasets in Excel where a column will have many cells with long text of around 1000 words. Therefore highlighting the entire column before copying and pasting isn't applicable. Thank you.

Comment: I have just tried this: Press `Ctrl-a` to select the whole sheet, `Ctrl-c` to copy, open `Word` and finally `Ctrl-v` to paste. Worked flawlessly for content 42 pages long.

Comment: If you hover the cursor over a column (where the column letters are), the cursor turns into a down arrow, and you can click to select the entire column, or click and drag to select several entire columns. Also, CTRL-clicking will add discontinuous columns to the selection.

Answer (score 0):

*To Copy data from Excel and Paste it as Text only in Word, do the following.*

1. Copy the data you want to paste into Word.
2. Right click the Word document where you want to paste the data.
3. Choose Keep Text Only option, under the Paste Options.

The data will be pasted as normal text, not as a table, and the original data formatting will be removed.

*If you want to keep the original formatting while copying from Excel to Word, follow these steps.*

1. Copy the data from Excel and paste into Word.
2. Select the resulting Table.
3. Click Layout then "Convert to Text".
4. From the "Convert Table To Text" Dialog box, choose one
   separator to separate the text under the "Separate text with..." option.
5. Click the Tabs Radio Button.
6. Finish by clicking OK.

*The table will be converted to normal text, retaining the original formatting.*